# Please, need to add a special class

Tags: css, class, html

Im trying to add a third class before the "last" but how? I always get syntex errors if I add it like this:

```
<li class="THIRD CLASS" class="last"><a href="contact.php"class="transition">Contact Us</a></li>
```

Please help me,

Sincerely.

Comment: Just use one `class` attribute instead of two?

Comment: Class names can't have a space in them.

Comment: just a example. Its not the actual name. How exactly do I add a third class there? For a few reasons i must have 3 classes because of some scripting and other reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
<li class="last anotherclass"><a href="contact.php"class="transition">Contact Us</a></li>
```

They will be applied in the order they are declared.

Comment: Wow, thank you  very much! this very much solved my problem :) In 5 minutes I will check the answer as solved

Comment: No problem, techanilties suck and compilers and run-time errors can be less than helpful sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Never use whitespace in an identifier (let it be in CSS or Java or whatever). So `THIRD_CLASS`.

In order to use two styles together, put them in the same class attribute separated by whitespace

```
 <myTag class="my_style my_other_style"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't correct.  You should be using

```
<li class="THIRD_CLASS last"><a href="contact.php"class="transitio...
```

There are two differences:

1. I only use one class attributes separating the names by spaces
2. I renamed "THIRD CLASS" to "THIRD_CLASS" as class names shouldn't have spaces in them.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one class attribute per tag, and class names must be one word, eg

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
<li class="THIRD_CLASS last"><a href="contact.php"class="transition">Contact Us</a></li>
```

Comment: you cannot have spaces in a single class if you look at the question third class is actually one class not two

Comment: Just guessing, but probably because you can't have a space in a class name.

Comment: Why not edit my answer to add an _ or tell me in the comments, as this was just a spelling mistake?